# vanilla JavaScript when function is done, do something

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a vanilla JavaScript function from what i now have running i jQuery. What i want to do is to wait for two functions that load data from two different API requests. If both are empty then i want to do some stuff. I wrote both request functions now in JavaScript but i got stuck on the .when section. How would i create that in JavaScript.

the code now looks like this:

```
function Request1() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://user', true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function processRequest(e) {
         if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            ResultData1 = data;
         }
     };

     return (ResultData1)
}


function Request2() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://gameOrder', true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function processRequest(e) {
         if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            ResultData2 = data;
         }
     };

     return (ResultData2)
}

$.when(Request1(), Request2()).done(function (R1, R2) {

       if (ResultData1.length == 0 && ResultData2.length == 0) {

       // Do stuff here all works

       }
 });
```

how do i write the same

Comment: Take a look at [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: If you can use the native promises, do so, since the JQuery implementation of promises through `$.when()` does not conform with the Promise spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) you could wrap your request in a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all the requests to be done.

```js
function request (url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        resolve(data);
      } else if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        reject();
      }
    };
  });
}

Promise.all([
  request('https://user'),
  request('https://gameOrder')
]).then(function (results) {
  var r1 = results[0];
  var r2 = results[1];
  console.log('Done');
  if (r1.length == 0 && r2.length == 0) {
    // Do stuff
    console.log('Done');
  }
}).catch(function () {
  console.log('Error');
});
```

You could also use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) that already returns a promise.

```js
function getJson (response) {
  return response.json();
}

Promise.all([
  fetch('https://user').then(getJson),
  fetch('https://gameOrder').then(getJson)
]).then(function (results) {
  var r1 = results[0];
  var r2 = results[1];
  console.log('Done');
  if (r1.length == 0 && r2.length == 0) {
    // Do stuff
    console.log('Done');
  }
}).catch(function () {
  console.log('Error');
});
```

Comment: `.json()` will also return *a promise!*